Data and Stack Alignment in 64-bit ELF Executables
I have these variables declared at the beginning of the main function:
char v4[44];   
int fd;   
void *buf;   
int v7;  

Debugging the executable (64 bit), I noticed that there is an 4 byte padding after the buf pointer, so the stack looks like this:
<--- rbp (base pointer)
v7 (4 bytes)
padding (4 bytes)
buf (8 bytes)
fd (4 bytes)
v4 (44 bytes)
<--- rsp (stack pointer after allocation)

This stack frame is build with:
sub rsp, 40h
For all the declared local variables, you would need 60 bytes. The stack frame is 64 bytes. Is this because of "stack alignment"? As far as I know, none of these variables would require data alignment. Why is the padding placed between these variables?

Does this answer your question? Why more space on the stack frame is reserved than is needed in x86

Each function provides its callees with an aligned stack (16-byte), if callees couldn't rely on that, it would take more code & data (e.g. unwind info) to provide that because the amount of stack space needed to achieve best alignment would be dynamically variable (i.e. depending on who the caller was).


For all the declared local variables, you would need 60 bytes. The stack frame is 64 bytes. Is this because of "stack alignment"?

Yes.  See Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?

As far as I know, none of these variables would require data alignment.

Not true.  According to the ABI, the int variables require 4 byte alignment, and the void * requires 8 byte alignment.  Even though x86 does allow unaligned memory accesses without faulting, it's less performant, so most fundamental types in C require "natural alignment", i.e. aligned to their size.
So if the variables are to be placed on the stack in the order shown, then the 4-byte gap between v7 and buf is mandatory to maintain alignment.  (Or you could have a 4-byte gap before v7; that would also be fine.)
The compiler could of course choose to arrange them in a different order; there is no rule saying stack layout has to correspond to order of declaration in the source code.  If it arranged them in the order fd, v7, buf, v4 then they could all fit in 60 contiguous bytes.  (And if you enable compiler optimizations, you may find that something like this is done.)  But since we need 16-byte stack alignment as mentioned above, we'd have to waste the following 4 bytes anyway, so nothing would really be gained in this case.

Thanks for your answer! What I meant by 'As far as I know, none of these variables would require data alignment' is that since the addresses of both integers are multiples of 4, and the address of the pointer is a multiple of 8, none of these variables would need padding to fulfill data alignment in this case, right? Am I correct in understanding that the 4-byte padding between buf and v7 is placed there by the compiler to fulfill the 16-byte stack alignment, but the compiler could also insert this padding in other places to achieve stack alignment?
